# How to sorted data in xlsx column by openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I would like to save sorted data from A to Z by column C in my Excel file.

My code:

```
### EXCEL
# Set column names
A = 'SURNAME'
B = 'NAME'
C = 'sAMAccountName'

# Set worksheet
wb = Workbook() # create excel worksheet
ws_01 = wb.active # Grab the active worksheet
ws_01.title = "all inf" # Set the title of the worksheet
# Set first row
title_row = 1
ws_01.cell(title_row, 1, A) # cell(row, col, value)
ws_01.cell(title_row, 2, B)
ws_01.cell(title_row, 3, C)

data_row = 2
for user in retrieved_users:
    attributes = user['attributes']
    sAMAccountName = attributes['sAMAccountName']
    if(user_validation(sAMAccountName) == True):
        A = attributes['sn']
        B = attributes['givenName']
        C = sAMAccountName
        ws_01.cell(data_row, 1, str(A))
        ws_01.cell(data_row, 2, str(B))
        ws_01.cell(data_row, 3, str(C))
        data_row = data_row + 1
    
# Save it in an Excel file
decoded_users_all_inf = root_path + reports_dir + users_all_inf_excel_file
wb.save(decoded_users_all_inf)
```

Where and what I have put to my code to have this?

Comment: The best thing is to sort the data before you write to Excel. You can add a filter to the worksheet so that a user can sort columns in Excel but the sort must be executed manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort `retrieved_users`, then you can use the built-in `list.sort` with a `key` to access the `sAMAccountName`.

```py
retrieved_users = [
    {"attributes": {"sn": "a", "givenName": "Alice", "sAMAccountName": "z"}},
    {"attributes": {"sn": "b", "givenName": "Bob", "sAMAccountName": "x"}},
    {"attributes": {"sn": "c", "givenName": "Charlie", "sAMAccountName": "y"}},
    ]

retrieved_users.sort(key=lambda d: d["attributes"]["sAMAccountName"])
```

`retrieved_users` contains

```py
[{'attributes': {'sn': 'b', 'givenName': 'Bob', 'sAMAccountName': 'x'}},
 {'attributes': {'sn': 'c', 'givenName': 'Charlie', 'sAMAccountName': 'y'}},
 {'attributes': {'sn': 'a', 'givenName': 'Alice', 'sAMAccountName': 'z'}}]
```

On another note, you can do `ws.append(row)` to append entire rows at a time rather than doing `ws.cell(row, col, value)` three times:

```py
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.append(('SURNAME', 'NAME', 'sAMAccountName'))
```

is equivalent to

```py
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.cell(1, 1, 'SURNAME')
ws.cell(1, 2, 'NAME')
ws.cell(1, 3, 'sAMAccountName')
```

Comment: I have `retrieved_users` from `json` file and it look this `retrieved_users = data['entries']` for `for` loop. Where I should put `retrieved_users.sort(key=lambda d: d["attributes"]["sAMAccountName"])` to have sorted data?

Comment: Put sort between retrieving the users and the for loop.

Comment: thx, it's working lovely. I forgot about `tab` in python language